# MongoDB - query field to include separate words

Tags: node.js, regex, mongodb

I would like to be able to pass separate words to query to make MongoDB find all documents where the field (SearchField) contains all of those words. No matter in which order.

**Search field should contain all words at the same time in whatever order**

Right now I'm using the following query:

```
const searchWords = search.split(' ').join('.*');
db.collection.find({SearchField: {$regex: searchWords, $options : 'i'}})
```

But it only considers cases where the words are in the same order as they were given.

I'm wondering if there's a way to make such query out-of-the box or should I use a combination of multiple queries (e.g. to find everything with word1, find everything with word2, etc. and find the interception).

Comment: Apparently you're not big on looking at things and learning. *"Find everything with word1, word2 etc"* means OR. So you were just shown how to contruct a list of OR expressions either in the query syntax or the "regex" syntax from a "list of words". This is the question you are asking, and this question has been answered before.

Comment: Well, I’ve solved it already with $and however. Find everything where both words occur means $and if you ask me. The program is working. And thank you for your comment. Was just going to post an answer. But you were fast to mark as duplicate. Anyway,

const searchWords = search.split(' ').map((word) => {
      return {SearchField: {$regex: word, $options: 'i'}};
    });


    MovieInfo.find({ "$and": searchWords})